# Carousel not displaying cards right after getting data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i need some help with one problem, i tried to make a card carousel getting data from my mysql database, all went well but the cards are displayed under each other not like it should be displayed in a carousel/slider, any ideas how could i fix this to show them in one line?
here is my code and a picture:

[image: embedded image]

```
    <?php
      include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>carusel</title>
  </head>
  <body>





    <section class="container p-t-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Bootstrap 4 Card Slider</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="postsCarousel">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-md-right lead">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary prev" href="" title="go back"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary next" href="" title="more"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container p-t-0 m-t-2 carousel-inner">
             <div class="row row-equal carousel-item active m-t-0">
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
                $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);
                if ($resultCheck > 0){
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { ?>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-img-top">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $row['avatar']; ?>" alt="Carousel">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['user_first'].' '.$row['user_last']; ?></h5>
                        <p><?php echo $row['card_text_profil']; ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php echo $row['profil_link']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Profil site</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  </body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Too many `</div>`s in your while loop. Close as many as you have `<div>`s in your `while` loop. Remember to close the `<div>`s from outside your `while` loop.

Comment: @kerbholz - it looks like 2 too many </divs>

Comment: Well, i rewrited it correctly, without 2 divs and i put as many as i could outside the while loop, but still are showing up one under each other...

Comment: Can you maybe update your code in the question to reflect the changes? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing 2 `</div>` inside the `while` loop, but they are being opened before the `while` loop, you need to add them to the beginning of the `while` loop.

Added a condition to check if it's the first element in the carousel, and if it is, add the `active` class as required per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/).

> Initial active element required The .active class needs to be added to
>   one of the slides. Otherwise, the carousel will not be visible.

The code I suggest as an answer makes it a lot more readable, this makes it a lot easier to prevent problems of this nature. Indentation goes a long way to help you see clearly where a block/loop starts and where it ends.

[Working minimal fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/87oLrwac/18/).

Replace:

```
<div class="container p-t-0 m-t-2 carousel-inner">
         <div class="row row-equal carousel-item active m-t-0">
             <div class="col-md-4">
    <?php

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
      $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);

      if ($resultCheck > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {


          //echo '<tr><th scope="row">'.$row['user_id'].'</th><td>'.$row['user_last']."</td><td>".$row['user_uid']."</td></tr>";
          /*echo '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">';
          echo '<img class="card-img-top" src="'.$row['avatar'].'" alt="Card image cap">';
          echo '<div class="card-body">';
          echo '<h5 class="card-title">'.$row['user_first'].' '.$row['user_last'].'</h5>';
          echo '<p class="card-text">'.$row['card_text_profil'].'</p>';
          echo '<a href="'.$row['profil_link'].'" class="btn btn-primary">Profil site</a>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';*/
          echo '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">';
          echo '<div class="card-img-top">';
          echo '<img class="img-fluid" src="'.$row['avatar'].'" alt="Carousel">';
          echo'</div>';
          echo '<div class="card-body">';
          echo '<h5 class="card-title">'.$row['user_first'].' '.$row['user_last'].'</h5>';
          echo '<p class="card-text">'.$row['card_text_profil'].'</p>';
          echo '<a href="'.$row['profil_link'].'" class="btn btn-primary">Profil site</a>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';




        }
      }
    ?>





     </div>
```

With:

```
<div class="container p-t-0 m-t-2 carousel-inner">
  <?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
  $i = 1;
  $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);
  if ($resultCheck > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { ?>
      <?php if($i % 2 != 0): //add new slider every odd row ?>
          <div class="row row-equal carousel-item <?php echo ($i == 1) ? "active" : ""; ?> m-t-0">
      <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-img-top">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $row['avatar']; ?>" alt="Carousel">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['user_first'].' '.$row['user_last']; ?></h5>
              <p><?php echo $row['card_text_profil']; ?></p>
              <a href="<?php echo $row['profil_link']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Profil site</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <?php if($i % 2 != 0): //add new slider every odd row ?>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe also add the `</div>`s for the two `<div>` before the `while` loop.

Comment: Still showing under each other... And when i do it with pure html without getting the data from mysql, it's all fine, is showing the slider how it should be...

Comment: @kerbholz I updated my answer, thanks for the heads-up !

Comment: @AndyS. I updated my answer can you give it another go? The extension of the code which needs to be replaced has also been updated.

Comment: Well, i replaced it with what you sent me, but still nothing good, the cards are still showing one under each other.

Comment: @AndyS. Maybe move your `<script>` tags at the end _before_ the `</body>`?

Comment: @kerbholz well, it's the same, didn't had any changes.

Comment: @AndyS. I updated the code yet again, turns out the 2 extra divs need to also be inside the while. Also, I added a condition to check if it's the first item in the array, if it is add the `active`class.

Comment: Here we go: every "item" in your bootstrap slide needs to have a class of `carousel-item`. Right now, you have _one_ element with that class and inside that element you have all your cards. Remove the class `carousel-item` in your current code (outside your `while`) and add it to your card. Also, all of your cards are inside a `div` with class `col-md-4`, that's why they only take 1/3rd of the space.

Comment: @AmmoPT now is working, but is only one problem: [link]http://prntscr.com/kmeckf [link]http://prntscr.com/kmectz now is showing one up, and then i can slide into another 1, but i would like to see more than 1 in the slide, or is just because that i do have just 2 people in the database?

Comment: @AndyS. You want to have 2 cards per slide, is that it? If my answer answers the original question, would you mind accepting it as an answer then?

Comment: I don't mind, you helped me a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: @AmmoPT would be kind from you if you could help me put 2 or 3 cards per slide

Comment: @AndyS. I have updated the code again, and the fiddle. Check it out. You need to add `.carousel-item.active {
    display: flex;
}` to your CSS. It has `display:block` on default and will always push cards below each other otherwise.

Comment: Well i did that, and i pasted the new code but it still pushing one of the cards below the other, the slider works, i edited the css but still isn't working.

Comment: You need to add the css after the bootstrap.css. Or it will never override.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kmevae http://prntscr.com/kmevfm i did it.. but still isn't working.. ;-?

Answer (score 0):

what about this css files do you float the picture divs?

Comment: That's not an answer, just another question.

Comment: /* equal card height */
.row-equal > div[class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.row-equal .card {
   width: 100%;
}

/* ensure equal card height inside carousel */
.carousel-inner>.row-equal.active, 
.carousel-inner>.row-equal.next, 
.carousel-inner>.row-equal.prev {
    display: flex;
}

/* prevent flicker during transition */
.carousel-inner>.row-equal.active.left, 
.carousel-inner>.row-equal.active.right {
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: flex;
}


/* control image height */
.card-img-top-250 {
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

Comment: @kerbholz cant commit.. :(

Comment: @AndyS. can i see it online too?

Comment: You can't comment, I know, we've all been there. Stick to questions that can be easily answered without asking any further questions.

Comment: roger that, will not happen again